# QRCode generate OFFLINE

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, qr-code

Is there an objective-c library which will allow me to generate QRCodes offline? 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create png image from QRCode for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087224/create-png-image-from-qrcode-for-iphone)

Answer (score 6):

See: https://github.com/jverkoey/ObjQREncoder#readme

To use

```
#import <QREncoder/QREncoder.h>

UIImage* image = [QREncoder encode:@"http://www.google.com/"];
```

Comment: Dude, You Saved My Life. Haven't tried this but looks promising..Thanks man!

Comment: it also can't seem to encode large pieces of text, like larger than 35 characters.  i figured a way to encode larger text, look at QREncoder.m at the function named `+ (UIImage *)encode:(NSString *)str`.  change the `correctionLevel` to something else like `QRCorrectionLevelLow`.  on the low setting it let me encode larger text

Comment: Kinda of a late reply but if you look at the example code you will see how to make it not blurry.

Answer (score 3):

In Mavericks and iOS7 QR code generation is part of Core Image. You just use the [CIQRCodeGenerator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIQRCodeGenerator) filter. On Github you can find a [class](https://github.com/hohl/MIHQRCodeView/blob/master/Classes/MIHQRCodeView.m) which implements this for iOS. I've adapted this code to get the OS X compatible code below:

```
NSString *website = @"http://stackoverflow.com/";
NSData *urlAsData = [website dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];
[filter setDefaults];

[filter setValue: urlAsData forKey:@"inputMessage"];
[filter setValue:@"M" forKey:@"inputCorrectionLevel"];

CIImage *outputImage = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
```

If you want to draw the CIImage there are several possibilities. You can create an `NSImage` like this:

```
CIContext *context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] CIContext];
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:outputImage
                                   fromRect:[outputImage extent]];

NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage size:NSZeroSize];
```

But this image will typicall be much smaller than you want. I believe each black dot in the QR code just becomes one pixel. Not quite what you want. To scale up the image without making it blurry, do this:

```
NSSize largeSize = NSMakeSize(image.size.width * 10, image.size.height * 10);

[image setScalesWhenResized:YES];
NSImage *largeImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:largeSize];
[largeImage lockFocus];
[image setSize:largeSize];
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationNone];
[image drawAtPoint:NSZeroPoint fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, largeSize.width, largeSize.height) operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
[largeImage unlockFocus];
```

`largeImage` is then your result image which you can display.

If you want to decode a QR you use AVFoundation as explained in this [blog](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/10/11/ios7-day-by-day-day-16-decoding-qr-codes-with-avfoundation). Unfortunately this seems to only be supported on iOS7 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple and native way of generating the QR code:

- (CIImage *)createQRForString:(NSString *)qrString {

  NSData *stringData = [qrString dataUsingEncoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

  CIFilter *qrFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];

  [qrFilter setValue:stringData forKey:@"inputMessage"];

  return qrFilter.outputImage;
  }